# Как проверить наличие ссылки в тексте?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение.

Есть текст и нужно проверить, есть ли в тексте ссылка, НО, только по таким вот комбинациям:

```
.ru
. ru
www.
www .
http:
```

Ну, в общем, я кое-как что-то набросал, но нужно подправить мою идею, а то я не особо силен в регулярках и сомневаюсь, что даже эта будет работать:

```
$filter="/(\.| )(ru|net|рф|com|tk|su|org|info|name|pro|biz|tv|ua|kz|am|mobi|me|us)(| )/i";
if (preg_match($filter, $text)) {
//
}
```

Comment: а что за `www .` ну вы тесты набросайте и проверяйте себе... вот здесь можно например:
http://www.debuggex.com/r/HBQmeSi9kXiQEkbW

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Приведите конкретные примеры текста и желаемый результат. Приведите примеры текста, которые дают не желаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Вот регулярное выражение, удовлетворяющее всем указанным условиям:

```
/(\.\s?ru|www\s?\.|http:)/i
```

Проверить работу можно вот здесь: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uC0iK7/2)